# LaTeX document to epub or mobi ebook formats (with mathematical formulas)

Tags: ebook

Recently I purchased an ebook reader (Kindle), and I want to export some of my document in LaTeX to an ebook format.

I tried exporting from LaTeX to PDF, but isn't perfect because I have to zoom in-out and move around the page many times (isn't confortable like when you read a normal ebook purshased in book stores).
I tried too exporting to RTF, but ***none*** of my mathematical formulas were in the output document.

So, do you know a better way to export from LaTeX  documents to ebook formats that includes **mathematical formulas**? And, that works with Kindle (mobipocket)!

Comment: What I usually do is to set the document size to (a bit less than) the screen size of the Kindle and remove all margins. This works quite well on a Kindle DX, as its screen size is around the page size of a paperback. Not sure how pleasing the result is on a normal-size Kindle.

Comment: @diegocaro: You haven't selected any answer or posted any comments. Are you still missing something?

Comment: EPUB 3 supports mathml. However, no handheld reading devices support EPUB 3 yet. Kindle does not support mathml and probably will not in the foreseeable future. A further problem with Kindle is that images cannot be rendered inline in text, so you can only use images for displayed math.

Comment: i was also using the Kindle reader for reading the Ebook, but this 6" device was not able to read some technical books related to my Engineering subject. i tried so many converters to make it readable but none of them helped to achieve the same. After several hours of search, i finally found [this thread](http://forums.techarena.in/portable-devices/1455402.htm) which helped to solve the problem.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/recommended-workflow-latex-epub-with-math-viewable-on-ipad , which has some more up to date discussion.

Comment: I've got a latex template that produces kindle sized pdf files (see my below answer): https://github.com/Todd-Davies/latex-template

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41402/6412

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`tex4ht` does an excellent job at converting LaTeX to (X)HTML, and it can convert math to either bitmap or MathML in the process. From there, you can use Calibre to convert the HTML to EPUB or MOBI.

For example, if you want to produce XHTML with MathML, using UTF-8 encoding, you can do:

```
mk4ht htlatex youfile.tex 'xhtml,charset=utf-8,pmathml' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

See [the documentation](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html) for more examples.

On [Wikipedia's LaTeX example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Example), this produces a MOBI file which looks like this in Kindle PC Reader:

[image: LaTeX to mobi, with formulas]

There's probably a bit to fine-tune, but the idea is there, you get the formulas. Fine-tuning might include disabling ligatures for example.

Note that the tuning might be done in the XHTML to MOBI conversion process, possibly with Calibre's options, since the HTML document looks fine:

[image: latex to XHTML]

Answer (score 8):

This works for me.

I use document class **memoir** with parameters `[ebook,oneside,openany]` with very few modifications respect to the original file (the one that produces PDF).

Compile it with: `htlatex myfile "html"`. Then load the resulting myfile.html in **Sigil**. Here I add missing metadata, split the chapters and mark the cover page image. Then save as epub and load it (via Calibre) on my reader.

Comment: With experience I'm improving the workflow. Now I load the htlatex output in Calibre, then convert to EPUB, then edit with Sigil for TOC, metadata and cover. The result is almost perfect.

Comment: Using `memoir`'s `ebook` option makes perfectly sense if you want to read your document as a native PDF on your reader. I don't see the point in using that when converting to EPUB or MOBI, though.

Comment: As I am creating pdfs and ebooks I recommend using image sizes relative to the page size: `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{file}`

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
```

or similar? worked fine with me. The size is adequate and you do not need to zoom in or out. If it is still difficult to read you can set the font size a bit.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to make too much change, go on with Andresmp answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50568/13993), and add this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{...}
\usepackage[hmargin=3.75em]{geometry} 
...
```

It would give you this, even if you're working with fancy package (but beware of the header/footer size) :

[image: "Kindle size"]

Rather than that :

[image: A4 version]

The increasing may look isn't that huge, but I can ensure you does work fine.

Hope that help you.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, ePub is similar to / based on HTML, so you could go from latex to HTML, then to ePub.

Comment: But it doesn't support mathematical formula

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html)? Possibly with the `--webtex` option to convert MathML to SVG.

Comment: It doesn't support mathematical formula :(

Comment: @diegocaro: Recent versions of pandoc translate TeX math to MathML.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [plastex](http://plastex.github.io/plastex/) ? Then Sigil to assemble the ePub.