# Convert Latex with lots of math to web-friendly format

Tags: pandoc, markdown

My math notes have a bunch of align environments (proofs) and I hope to post them on the Web.

Currently I'm thinking about using pandoc to convert tex to markdown, then use jekyll to build my site. However, from the pandoc demo it is hard to gauge how well the translation is done.

I'm also open to any other solution about posting math tex notes on the Web.

Comment: MathJax (a javascript library) can be used to render some LaTeX math on the web. The demo is [here (click)](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/).

Comment: you can also use `tex4ht`. it can be configured to use `mathjax` for math rendering on the web. it can be also configured to produce html suitable for producing with `jekyll`, see https://github.com/michal-h21/michal-h21.github.com/blob/master/_texposts/2012/02/2012-02-14-Blogujeme-s-LaTeXem.tex and generated html: https://github.com/michal-h21/michal-h21.github.com/blob/master/_posts/2012-02-14-Blogujeme-s-LaTeXem.html

Comment: @michal.h21 Your example is promising but does not have a lot of math. Do you have experience with this?

Comment: tex4ht and latexml can both convert a lot of documents including math, this question has been asked several times on this site, I'll dig out some links

Comment: yes, try to search this site for `tex4ht mathjax`. there are two possible options, to convert math to mathml and use mathjax just to display math without mathml support, or keep math as LaTeX and use mathjax to display it in all browsers. maybe you could add some example document to your question, so we can see which features you need. and as David said, similar question has been asked in the past, but none of the were about format suitable ffor jekyll, afaik

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-do-i-convert-html-to-latex/3083#3083  or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43847/why-havent-any-tex-html-converters-been-updated-to-use-current-web-standards-s/43852#43852 or just search this site for "html" :-)

Comment: tex4ht is amazingly powerful. It can cope with pretty much anything that latex can throw at it, including mathematics and images created using pstricks or tikz. There is a bit of a learning curve but I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks all for your help -- after searching the sites, there are indeed options to convert LaTeX to html. However, from then on I'll have to host those html myself. There doesn't seem to be something compatible with jekyll in order to take advantage of jekyll's convenience yet.