# Best workflows or tools to generate an html web page from a complex latex document like thesis

Tags: conversion, html, thesis, pandoc, css

I'm really interested to publish my thesis on a website HTML + CSS (when it's done) augmented with tools to [annotate it](http://annotatorjs.org/), like the philoweb initative (see [here](http://hackyourphd.org/en/2014/01/phd-thesis-towards-openscience-practices-philoweb-org-as-an-exemple-on-december-13rd-at-la-fonderie-paris/), and [here](http://philoweb.org/)).

I know the universal converter [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) or the latex2html, but i'm interested to know if others tools exists, or if some users already create a batch workflow to make this conversion automaticaly.

Perhaps it can be a community wiki question ?

**Updated list (16 april 2015) :**

- [tex4ht](http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)
- [latexml](http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/)
- [latex2html](http://LaTeX2HTML) (discontinued)
- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)
- [Support](https://github.com/substance/substance/issues/74) for latex in great [Substance.io](http://substance.io/composer/) composer for web, used by [elife lens open source solution](https://medium.com/@_mql/self-host-a-scientific-journal-with-elife-lens-f420afb678aa) (to survey)

**MWE creation :**

I propose a first link to collaborate on a complex MWE to test these tools, which contain all complex elements you want :

[Link to public MWE on sharelatex](https://fr.sharelatex.com/project/55263f20ea4bb3bd510aeb80)

**Things to transform and eventually beautify with some js :**

- Math
- Complex Side Caption
- Bibliography
- Public annotation

**Example of great conversion :**

- http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_toc_sc.html

Comment: Perhaps... but meanwhile maybe you need to use something more than HTML and CSS. Have you seen something about [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) before? I don't know how complex were the mathematical expressions that you used in your thesis. If they are not so, you could even use something less sophisticated such as the [Beautiful Maths plugin from the Jetpack bundle](http://jetpack.me/) used in [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/).

Comment: the question of tex to html convertors must be a duplicate, I'll find an older question. tex4ht and latexml are probably the two most robust convertors that you don't mention.

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43847/why-havent-any-tex-html-converters-been-updated-to-use-current-web-standards-s?rq=1

Comment: it is easy to add javascript with `tex4ht`, we just need some sample document to work with

Comment: Yes, perhaps i can propose a MWE example to transform in Html, memoir class, with latex Math equation, Svg or Png images, include .tex, tikz image, etc ? Did you see other things ?

Comment: @reyman64 yeah, something like that

Comment: I create a collaborative MWE on sharelatex, i try to work on this later this week end.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an MWE here. Questions should be self-contained so that they remain useful even if the content of external links changes or disappears.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will show a solution with `tex4ht`.  I used your sample text and added some math samples from the internet. You can see the complete resulting webpage on my [Github page](http://michal-h21.github.io/reyman/thesis.html). All code is also hosted on [Github](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-enhanced-web).

You have four wishes, some of them can be solved using external Javascript tools, for others we must create custom JS scripts.

`tex4ht` can be configured using `.cfg` file. This file has special structure:

```
...
\Preamble{xhtml,list of options}
...
\begin{document}
...
\EndPreamble
```

we can require some packages before `\Preamble` command, which we may use for some helper packages. In our example, we may need two packages:

- one for fixes some issues with Memoir under `tex4ht`
- other with some helper macros

you need recently updated TeX Live for latest bug fixes for `tex4ht` Memoir support, in this case you need only fo fix this issue with double Bibliography entry in the TOC.

This can be fixed with `mem4hack.sty`:

```
\renewcommand\@memb@bchap{\chapter*{\bibname}\bibmark\prebibhook}
```

the other supporting package is `tools.sty`:

```
\newcommand\AddFile[1]{\special{t4ht+@File: #1}}%

\newcommand\AddCss[1]{%
  \AddFile{#1}%
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#1" />}}
}

\newcommand\AddJs[1]{%
  \AddFile{#1}%
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript" src="#1"></script>}}
}
```

This simplifies inclusion of `CSS` and `JS` files in your project.

Regarding used libraries, we can use `mathjax` for math support and
[`hypothes.is`](https://hypothes.is/) for annotating. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with local pages, you have to use a webserver (but you can install it on your local computer, you don't need actual server).

Math example:

[image]

annotation examples:

[image]
[image]

For sidebar, you can make a standalone file for each chapter, with local TOC for sections and subsections. So you can make sidebar containing this TOC and links to previous and next chapter.

The code is here `js/sidebar.js`:

```javascript
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Code
    // select local TOC
    var menu = q(".chapterTOCS")[0];
    var menuopened = "^^^";
    var m = createEl("a","menu",menuopened);
    var toolbar = createEl("div","toolbar");
    var sidebar = createEl("div","sidebar","");
    var crosslinks = q(".crosslinks")[0];
    var setText = function(node,a){
      var text = document.createTextNode(a);
      node.removeChild(node.childNodes[0]);
      node.appendChild(text);
    }
    var switchMenu = function(){
      // switch menu state
      menu.className = hiddenswitch ? "chapterTOCS red" : "chapterTOCS hiddentoc";
      var text = hiddenswitch ? menuopened:"TOC"  ;
      // set menu class to changed state
      setText(m, text);

      hiddenswitch = !hiddenswitch;
    }
    // pass reference to new container and crosslinks
    var transfromCrosslinks = function(newcrosslinks,el){
      // find all crosslinks 
      var links = el.querySelectorAll("a");
      var newcrs = {}
     // make table with link text as name
     for(i=0;i!=links.length;i++){
          var text = links[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
          newcrs[text] = links[i];
      }
      // select next, prev and up nodes and replace text with unicode arrows
      // is a node doesn't exist, create span with blanklink class
      var next = newcrs["next"] || createEl("span","blanklink",">")
      setText(next,"⇨");
      var prev = newcrs["prev"]|| createEl("span","blanklink",">")
      setText(prev,"⇦");
      setText(newcrs["up"],"⇧");
      // add crosslinks to a toolbar
      newcrosslinks.appendChild(prev);
      newcrosslinks.appendChild(newcrs["up"]);
      newcrosslinks.appendChild(next);
      crosslinks.remove();
      return newcrosslinks;
    }
    // add elements to the sidebar depending on existence of a local TOC and 
    // crosslinks
    if(crosslinks){
      transfromCrosslinks(toolbar,crosslinks);
      // add sidebat only if it doesn't exist already
      if(!menu) sidebar.appendChild(toolbar);
      //m.appendChild(newcrosslinks);
    }
    if(menu) { 
      toolbar.appendChild(m);
      sidebar.appendChild(toolbar);
      sidebar.appendChild(menu);
    }
    q("body")[0].appendChild(sidebar);
    var hiddenswitch = false
    m.on("click",switchMenu,false);
    //menu.insertBefore(m,menu.childNodes[0]);

 }, false);
```

this uses standard Javascript DOM functions, only small library `js/fw.js` is being used:

```javascript
// basic DOM functions
// based on http://blog.adtile.me/2014/01/16/a-dive-into-plain-javascript/
var q = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
Element.prototype.on = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
var createEl = function(el, cls, text){
  var x = document.createElement(el);
  x.setAttribute("class",cls);
  if(text) {
    var t = document.createTextNode(text);
    x.appendChild(t);
  }
  return x;
}
```

[image]

The `TOC` can be hidden by click on the `^^^` text.

[image]

For bibliography, we can load bibliography page using `AJAX` and show the citations in a window when you point a cursor over a citation. Window can be closed by clicking anywhere in the document.

File `js/bib.js`:

```javascript
var bibdoc = null;

var isBibbox = function(){
  return q("#bibbox").length>0;
}

var makeBibTooltip = function(bib,id,el){
  if(!isBibbox()){
    var xxx = bib.querySelector(id).parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    var parentpos = el.getBoundingClientRect();  
    var tip = document.createElement("div");
    tip.setAttribute("id", "bibbox")
    tip.style.position = "fixed";
    tip.style.top = parentpos.bottom+ 10+"px";
    tip.style.left = parentpos.left+ 10 +"px" ;
    tip.appendChild(xxx);
    document.body.appendChild(tip);
  }
}
var getBibDoc = function(url,id,el){
  if(!bibdoc){
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("Load ajax"+url)
    bibdoc = ajax.open("GET",url,true);
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status==200 && !bibdoc){
        var res = ajax.responseText;
        bibdoc = createEl("div","bib");
        bibdoc.innerHTML = res;
        makeBibTooltip(bibdoc,id,el);
      }
    }
  }else{
    makeBibTooltip(bibdoc,id,el);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var bibs = q("span.cite");
  for(i=0;i<bibs.length;i++){
    bibs[i].on("mouseover", function(e){
      var el = e.currentTarget;
      var link = el.querySelector("a");
      var hash = link.hash;
      var href = link.getAttribute("href");
      getBibDoc(href,hash,el);
      //var target = bib.querySelector("body");
      //console.log("nazdar "+ target);
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener("click",function(){
  if(isBibbox()){
    var bibbox = q("#bibbox");
    for(i=0;i<bibbox.length;i++){
      bibbox[i].remove();
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

We can also make a better typography, I really like [Viljami Salminen's
responsive CSS boilerplate](https://github.com/viljamis/Scale). Use the `css/scale.css` file.

We can put it all together now, make file `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\RequirePackage{mem4hack}
\RequirePackage{tools}
\Preamble{xhtml,2,mathml}
 \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
 src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
 ></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script async defer src="http://hypothes.is/embed.js"></script>}}
\AddCss{css/scale.css}
\AddJs{js/fw.js}
\AddJs{js/sidebar.js}
\AddJs{js/bib.js}

% fix sublist indentation

\Css{li li{margin-left:2em;}}
\Css{dd dl{margin-left:2em;}}

% we can use helper macros to use variables in the CSS
\def\numcalc#1{\the\numexpr #1\relax}
\def\sidebarwidth{18}
% sidebar is on a fixed position. you should play with this
\Css{.sidebar{position:fixed;width:\sidebarwidth em;top:3em;left:100\%;margin-left:-\numcalc{\sidebarwidth+2}em;}}
% fix local TOC formating 
\Css{.sidebar .sectionToc,.sidebar .subsectionToc{display:block;margin-top:-1em;margin-bottom:0px;}}
\Css{.sidebar .chapterTOCS br{display:none;}}
% we can turn off the local TOC 
\Css{.hiddentoc{display:none;}}
% TOC switch formatting
\Css{.menu{margin-left:1em;}}
\Css{.menu red{font-size:0,7em;vertical-align:sub;}}
% toolbar displays links to previous and next chapters and TOC switcher
\Css{.toolbar{font-size:1.3em;background-color:\#fed;}}
% tooltip which displays bibliographic record when you point 
% a cursor on a citation
\Css{\#bibbox{border:1px solid black;background-color:\#fed;width:25em;}}
% make standalone page for each chapter. make local TOC for contained sections
% and subsections
\TocAt{chapter,section,subsection}
\begin{document}
% we can delete normal TOC, it is created automatically by tex4ht and it 
% would be duplicated
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@ifstar{}{}}
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

In the `\Preamble` command, options for `tex4ht` are specified. `xhtml` requests `xhtml` output, `2` breaks document into standalone web page at every `\chapter` (`1` would break it at every part, `3` at every section ...), `mathml` requests conversion of math to `mathml`.

Configurations should go after `\Preamble` command.

Internal `js` and `CSS` files are included using `\AddJs` resp. `\AddCss` commands. `mathjax` and `hypothes.is` are included using links to external pages, which is configured using

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{...}
```

this configuration add stuff to the html `<head>` element.

You can add `CSS` styles using `\Css` command. The included styles are pretty basic, you may want to (and really should) modify them for better look, concentrated only on functionality, not aesthetics)

Now you can compile your file using

```
htlatex thesis myconfig
```

or better, use [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) which is
alternative build system for `tex4ht`. This build file will copy all used files
to `/var/www/html/reyman/` directory, so you can open in your browser this
address: [localhost/reyman/thesis.html](http://localhost/reyman/thesis.html)
and everything should work. If you have Unix like system, Apache web server and
write permissions to that directory. File `thesis.mk4`:

```lua
local mkutils = require "mkutils"
local outdir = "/var/www/html/reyman/"
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:add("bibtex", "bibtex ${input}")
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:bibtex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
Make:match(".*$", function(file, par)
  mkutils.copy(file, outdir .. file)
  return false, "Copy html to destination "..outdir
end)
```

Compile with

```
make4ht -u -c myconfig thesis
```

to speedup the compilation, you can use

```
make4ht -um draft -c myconfig thesis
```

which will compile the document only once with LaTeX and it will skip the `bibtex`.

You can see the result on my [Github page](http://michal-h21.github.io/reyman/thesis.html)

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer :) The comment is lost after earch regen of the file ? Thanks !

Comment: @reyman64 it's not lost after you register and login to `hypotes.is`.  it works even on localhost