# Converting xparse commands to html

Tags: tex4ht, html, xparse, pandoc

I've had a varying level of success converting LaTeX documents into HTML, but one of the major problems I've encountered is converting expressions which contain commands defined through the xparse package. For example,

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\derivative{ s o m g d() }
{ % Total derivative
    % s: star for \flatfrac flat derivative
    % o: optional n for nth derivative
    % m: mandatory (x in df/dx)
    % g: optional (f in df/dx)
    % d: long-form d/dx(...)
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\let\fractype\flatfrac}
    {\let\fractype\frac}
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}
    {
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}
        {\fractype{\diffd \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}}}{\diffd #3\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}}}}
        {\fractype{\diffd \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}}}{\diffd #3\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}}} \argopen(#5\argclose)}
    }
    {\fractype{\diffd \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}} #3}{\diffd #4\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\sp{#2}}}}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\dv{}{\derivative} % Shorthand for \derivative
```

is a command to typeset a derivative, so `$\dv{x}{t}$` will produce a nicely formatted dx/dt notation. This example is taken from the [physics](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/physics?lang=en) package from CTAN, but I use a number of similar macros in day-to-day work. Is there a way to either convert these macros into standard tex markup before passing the file to e.g. pandoc, or is there a way to convert them as part of the html conversion process, so that they can be rendered in MathML or by MathJax?

Comment: latexml (and also tex4ht) should in some sense be able to follow the macro definitions but you don't really want to expand/translate all of xparse every time, most systems, certainly tex4ht and mathjax allow you to specify custom conversions, so in mathjax's case you just need to define `\derivative` in javascript and add that javascript code as an extension in the mathjax customisation object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert math to `mathml` with `tex4ht`, you only need to provide `mathml` option:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,mathml"
```

for your example, the result is following:

[image]

```html
<math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><mfrac><mrow 
><mi mathvariant="normal">d</mi><mi 
>x</mi></mrow>
<mrow 
><mi mathvariant="normal">d</mi><mi 
>t</mi></mrow></mfrac> </math>
```

Comment: I feel rather daft now; that seems to work where my previous attempt with mathjax fails... Thanks!

Comment: @lpmn mathjax just supports TeX-like syntax, it really doesn't support custom macros without configuration. you can combine mathjax with mathml in order to support browsers without mathml support. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239944/2891 for example