# Is it possible to create a web page which appears same/similar in formatting to the pdf generated from latex?

Tags: html, latex2html

Corresponding to a one-two page document such as a resume one might want to create a web page where one can scroll up/down with links to move to top-bottom at the end of each section.

Corresponding to a large document such as a 100 page report, one might want to create a 'website' with multilevel collapsible index on the left side of the 'website'. Through this one should be able to move to navigate to different parts of the report.

I have tried to generate a html file using .tex file. What I got was a very plain looking html file. Formatting wasn't great either. I am just exploring the possibility of generating web pages using my .tex file.

I am interested in web pages with following features:

1. No fancy stuff. Plain white background.
2. But, it should appear just like pages in my report (similar text width as in the report)
3. It should be possible to select/copy text.

Comment: I hope I have described things properly in my question.

Comment: TeXstudio can do this: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION36

Comment: You can use [tex4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht). It is very powerful and convert (almost?) any latex file into html. Typically you will want tweak the configuration a little and there is a learning curve...

Comment: yes you can use tex4ht. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239944/2891 for something similar, you can see the result here: http://michal-h21.github.io/reyman/thesis.html

Comment: [dvisvgm](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/) or [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) could be solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create a web page which appears same/similar in formatting to the pdf. One solution is that you generate PDF from LaTeX, and then convert the PDF to HTML via pdf2htmlEX. Other solutions could be found in our article on TUGboat, titled by *Online publishing via pdf2htmlEX* [HTML](https://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/doc/tb108wang.html)/[PDF](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/doc/tb108wang.pdf). The Figure 3 inside might be helpful.

Comment: PS: The link [HTML](https://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/doc/tb108wang.html) itself is an example of webpage which appears the same in formatting to the link [PDF](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/doc/tb108wang.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. I am able to generate the html file. I opened it (offline) in my browser and it appeared exactly the way I wanted it to appear. But the next issue is to add this html file to my website. Basically, I intend to view that html online instead of offline. How to add that html file to my google site or blogger account? I am not able to do so. I am sure I am missing something but am unable to figure it out and move ahead.