# Convert latex conference paper to html with figures and bibliographic references

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, html, latex2html

I wrote a paper for a conference in latex format. It contains figures and bibliographic references. I got the output in PDF format and it looks fine. Now I would like to convert it to HTML. I just tried "latex2html doc.tex". But the problem is that in the resulting HTML index.html format, although it does not look bad, the citation numbers do not appear on the text and the same for the figures, which are both in .eps and .jpg formats.

Is it there a better approach for doing this kind of conversions or am I missing some latex2html parameters?

Answer (score 3):

`tex4ht` is a much better LaTeX to HTML converter than `latex2html`. See my answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/latex-document-to-epub-or-mobi-ebook-formats-with-mathematical-formulas/17842#17842).

`tex4ht` uses standard LaTeX to produce a DVI and works from there to convert to HTML, so it supports a lot of things, including your own macros and tricky packages. I suppose (but haven't tested it myself) that bibliography and figures should work without a problem.