# Converting LaTeX doc with extensive math to portable eBook

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, epub, latexml

I posted the following question [10 years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/recommended-workflow-latex-epub-with-math-viewable-on-ipad), and the answers at the time were basically that there wasn't yet any particular good/easy solution, in part because of the immaturity of ePub3.  My only real update to the question itself would be that I would add Kindle and other common e-readers as targets along with IOS, again with the primary goal of reliably reproducing complex math, ideally with scalable (not rasterized) renderings.

> I'm looking for a workflow that will take me efficiently and reliably
> from existing LaTeX documents (e.g., books) with lots of (sometimes)
> complex embedded math to high-quality ePubs that will display nicely
> in iBooks under iOS6 and, ideally, on other readers as well (lower
> priority).
>
> I've been looking at LateXML, TeX4ht, plasTeX, XhtmLaTeX, pandoc,
> ebook-convert, and the tbook DTD (which starts with XML rather than
> LaTeX and thus looks promising primarily for new documents). All of
> these tools seem to have a lot to offer, but none of them, as far as I
> can tell, gets me to the finish line without what appears to be
> significant manual intervention (implying a need for significant
> learning/debugging as well). I haven't been able to decide yet which
> pathway is worth investing the time and energy on. Looking forward to
> an up-to-date assessment.
>
> I'll note that I already published an ePub textbook with equations
> rendered as SVG, and it displayed very nicely in iBooks under iOS5.
> Unfortunately, iOS6 broke it, and the eBook is now a virtual
> paperweight. I'm trying to recover and get the same book back into a
> usable ePub format that renders equations nicely.
>
> I don't mind investing in a commercial product if it's the least
> painful means to solve the problem, but I'd prefer to build a
> script-based workflow based on open-source tools for Mac OS X.

With another decade behind us since then, it seems likely that options have improved, so I'd welcome an update.

Comment: Has there been any change in ebook readers since then? It's not something I've revisited, and my main ebook reader (**not** a Kindle!) is still the same one I've had for many years so I've not been aware if there has been any improvement on that end.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd be disappointed if turned out the e-pub standards and software hadn't significantly changed in 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

If the Ebook is going to be distributed via a commercial outlet (such as for Kindle) then you probably cannot use any fonts other than the ones built into the reader software. Partly that is avoid potential technical issues, and partly that is to avoid having them re-distribute an embedded font for which they do not have the license.

Depending on various factors, some distributors may refuse files with vector graphics, other than the simplest kind. This is unlikely to change in the near future. It is because there are many ways to write vector graphics that will display as intended with some software, but not others. The bug is in the vector graphics, not the reader software. Just as with badly-written HTML, different software may apply different guesses as to what to do. So, if you can get your graphics working on an iPAY$ device, it may be unintelligible on Windows, Linux, Android, and maybe even OSX, or it may depend on which app is used for viewing.

And finally: A lot has happened in the past 10 years. Devices now have more screen resolution, much more memory, and much more storage. Depending on how many diagrams/equations you have, and whether they are simply black/white or grayscale/color, it may be practical to rasterize them to PNG. If black/white, they can be rasterized at 1-bit per pixel before PNG compression. If rasterized to 600ppi, an image can be magnified quite a bit before pixelization is noticeable.

There's always PDF. I believe that nearly any device (including Kindle) can read it, if it does not rely on exotic features.

Comment: You wrote "there are many ways to write vector graphics that will display as intended with some software, but not others."  I had thought that SVG was intended to be pretty device and software independent.  So, not true?
Also, in my past experience at least, raster images didn't scale with the surrounding text, so you could change the font size, but the equation images stayed the same size.  Has that changed as well?

Comment: @GrantPetty No matter how wonderful SVG, it is possible to write bad code. For example, consider TeX :) Without a comprehensive and accurate validity checker, bad vector graphics (any format, not just SVG) will exist. Simple example: Figure 8 drawn as a moebius strip, rather than as a single outside clockwise path, with two independent counter-clockwise holes. Happens all the time. That one is easy to catch, though. Also, commercial printer software converts vector to PNG. The more vectors, the more time waiting to print. Money is involved.

Comment: @GrantPetty As for scaling, that's what finger-spread on touchscreen is for. Fine if the image is at high pixel density.