# Convert LaTeX file to HTML or ePub

Tags: conversion, html, ebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use LaTeX to produce Epub](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub)

May be this question was asked before but I could not find relevant info to solve the problem. 
I have a need to convert my Latex file to ePub but I could not find much information. I have "Calibre" software which converts html to ePub. So I was wondering if there is a way I can convert my LaTeX file to Html.

If I can bypass converting html and somehow directly go to ePub that would be awesome. 
For novices like me a working example would be a great help.
Thank a lot for all your help

Comment: Since epub basically is html, I would consider this an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the ePub format is zipped (x)html, so any way of converting tex source to ePub will in effect create html or xhtml, so having html or xhtml as an intermediary is not as circuitous as it might seem.

The only application I know of that will directly take TeX source and output an ePub is [pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub) (newer versions).

As for using calibre, you could use [TeX4ht](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) (htlatex) to first convert the TeX to html, which you very likely already have installed.

For an overview of various converters, see [this blog post.](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-from-latex/)

Comment: The post you reference mentions [plasTeX](http://plastex.sf.net) as unfunctional, though it was the one I actually had most pleasant experience with.

Comment: That was just my personal experience with it. YMMV, of course. (I wrote the blog post in question.)

Comment: @frabjous: Don't forget this blog post either: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/getting-latex-on-to-the-web/, and this article: http://ncatlab.org/doriath/show/converting%20latex%20to%20itex was converted from latex source.

Comment: @eudoxos - Sorry to say but I have not installed TeX4ht(htlatex) to convert to html. Honestly I was trying to find how to do this conversion.

Comment: For me, it came pre-installed when I installed TeXlive.

Comment: Since the link to the blog post is dead now, read it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120702232709/http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-from-latex/