# TeX to epub conversion

Tags: conversion, png, svg, pandoc

I want to create epub document, but I only have a tex file (unfortunately, mathematical formulas, and drawing diagrams). I tried pandoc: tex to html, tex to xhtml, to xml, but nothing works properly. I use tikz.

You can do the epub file with png or svg?

Some ideas?

Comment: This question has been asked before several times. Look at the answers here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub. From my personal experience, every solution needs some tweaking. I've been playing with tex4ht to generate html, do some tweaking, build the epub with a script, some more tweaking and then calibre. As for images, I don't remember if epub supports svg, but it does support png.

Comment: Thx, I'll try, but I must have an automatic tool.

Comment: The tweaking I've mentioned I've managed to do it with a script. Actually, 2. One to convert to html and one to create the epub.

Comment: I've done a lot, but I can't do charts.

Comment: You're unlikely to get perfect results with pandoc, unless your tex file is pretty simple.  However, this might be of interest:  a pandoc filter that will process the tikz diagrams in your document and turn them into embedded images which can appear in the EPUB.  For background on pandoc filters, see <http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html>.

Comment: several ways exists for exporting tikz pictures as svg, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891 for example. you get html code for your document and svg only for pictures using this method, so it is easy convert it later to epub. it should be also compatible with https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook (but I haven't tested it yet), so you can convert directly from LaTeX to epub3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have solution.

1. create pdf (input.tex)

   ```
   pdflatex input.tex
   ```
2. create png

   ```
   convert -quality 05 input.pdf output.png
   ```
3. create html (png files have so much how many pages in PDF file, for example: 4)

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
       <style>
           img {
               display: block;
           }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <img src="output-0.png"/>
       <img src="output-1.png"/>
       <img src="output-2.png"/>
       <img src="output-3.png"/>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. create metadata for EPUB (`metadata.xml`)

   ```
   <dc:title>[ebook_name]</dc:title>
   <dc:identifier id="pub-id">[ebook_id]</dc:identifier>
   <dc:creator opf:file-as="[secondName,firstName]" opf:role="aut">[firstName secondName]</dc:creator>
   <dc:rights>[company]</dc:rights>
   <dc:language>[lang]</dc:language>
   <dc:publisher>[company]</dc:publisher>
   ```
5. create epub file

   ```
   pandoc -f html -t epub3 --epub-metadata=metadata.xml -o output.epub output.html
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet might be the tex -> pdf -> epub route. Calibre or other software can make a decent attempt, but it will probably not be fully automatic.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately there are problems with graphs. I must have an automatic conversion tool, Tex is built automatically, epub also must be built automatically.

Comment: Using pdf as an intermediate format is a disaster. Loses all semantic markup, many paragraphs, introduces new paragraphs at every page break. Just. Don't.