# Using htlatex with tikz-dependency

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, syntax, linguistics, htlatex

I am trying to generate an html file from a tex file using htlatex. The htlatex works well with simple tikz pictures, but it has problem with the pictures  (trees) drawn with tikz-dependency package. Here is my code copied from tikz-dependency manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=.5cm, row sep=.1ex]
PRP\$ \& NN \& RB \&[.5cm] VBZ \& VBG \& NN \\
My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot{4}{root}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\wordgroup{2}{4}{4}{pred}
\wordgroup{2}{1}{2}{a0}
\wordgroup{2}{5}{6}{a1}
\groupedge[edge below]{pred}{a0}{ARG0}{4ex} % pred -> a0 (ARG0, 4ex)
\groupedge[edge below]{pred}{a1}{ARG1}{6ex} % pred -> a1 (ARG1, 6ex)
\end{dependency}

\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.2cm]
My \&[.5cm] dog \& also \&[.7cm] likes \&[.4cm] eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

For second example, I get a nice tree, though without terminal-nodes (words). The first code throws an error in html. htlatex also doesn't work with qtree and xytree packages! 
Any help is highly appreciated. This thing is really getting on my nerves!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is known problem that `tex4ht pgfsysdriver` does have some problems with text nodes. In such cases, it is better to use `tikz externalization`.

There are some problems you need to solve:

1. `dependendency` environment doesn't support externalization. You can replace it with `tikzpicture` in your case
2. there are several ways to convert externalized pictures to `svg`, I did some tests and it seems best is to use `inkscape` in the command line mode
3. you need to configure `tex4ht` to include `svg` images.

So, you need to modify your file in such way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{
    tex4ht inc/.style={
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
            \includegraphics[]{##1.svg}%
        }

    }
}

\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
      {; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg" }    
}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
}{
    \tikzexternalize
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=.5cm, row sep=.1ex]
PRP\$ \& NN \& RB \&[.5cm] VBZ \& VBG \& NN \\
My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot{4}{root}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\wordgroup{2}{4}{4}{pred}
\wordgroup{2}{1}{2}{a0}
\wordgroup{2}{5}{6}{a1}
\groupedge[edge below]{pred}{a0}{ARG0}{4ex} % pred -> a0 (ARG0, 4ex)
\groupedge[edge below]{pred}{a1}{ARG1}{6ex} % pred -> a1 (ARG1, 6ex)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.2cm]
My \&[.5cm] dog \& also \&[.7cm] likes \&[.4cm] eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are several changes:

```
\tikzset{
        tex4ht inc/.style={
            /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
                \includegraphics[]{##1.svg}%
            }

        }
    }
```

This is a definition of new tikz style, used in `tex4ht` for `svg` inclusion.

```
\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
      {; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg"
            }    
}
```

this definition calls `inkscape` to convert `pdf` pictures to `svg`,

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
}{
    \tikzexternalize
}
\makeatother
```

and we need to use this code for correct inclusion of images in `tex4ht`.

Now you can generate pictures with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename
```

You also have to create configuration file for `tex4ht`, like `myconfig.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{graphics*}  
         {svg}{  
          {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
          \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}%  
         }  
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]  
\tikzset{tex4ht inc}
\EndPreamble
```

configuration for `svg` inclusion is provided here.

Now you can compile the document to `html` with

```
htlatex filename myconfig
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I copied and pasted your code as such and compiled it, unfortunately it didn't work. I only see PIC PIC in the ftml page generated not trees! I don't see any svg files generated. There are just pdf files.

Comment: @Riyaz do you have inkscape installed? maybe there are some error messages in the log file?

Comment: Sorry sh: 1: inkscape: not found

Comment: I installed the inkscape but still I have the same output. I tried inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg" outside the tex file it works, but not inside the tex

Comment: @Riyaz and do you compile your file with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename`?

Comment: Yes I did! I am very close to get it working. Some thing is wrong with the conversion of pdf into svg in the tex its not happening.

Comment: I can't give your solution an upvote as I don't have enough reputations, sorry for that! I finally got it working. Thanks a lot! BTW can I use the same solution for including the q-tree or qobitree tress. They also don't work.

Comment: @Riyaz if there packages aren't based on `tikz`, then they can't use this solution. but you can try tikz-qtree, it works

Comment: Yes tkz-qtree seems an alternative for both qtree and qobitree. Thanks any-ways michal for your help!

Comment: WOW! Works with tikz-qtree as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. Missing `\begin{document}`.
2. The command `\def\pgfsysdriver{...}` should go after `\usepackage{tikz,...}`, as some of the macros defined in the pgf driver require lower level macros defined by tikz-pgf.

The following code compiles all right for me with `pdflatex` and `htlatex`, both with and without externalized graphics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}

\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=.5cm, row sep=.1ex]
PRP\$ \& NN \& RB \&[.5cm] VBZ \& VBG \& NN \\
My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot{4}{root}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\wordgroup{2}{4}{4}{pred}
\wordgroup{2}{1}{2}{a0}
\wordgroup{2}{5}{6}{a1}
\groupedge[edge below]{pred}{a0}{ARG0}{4ex} % pred -> a0 (ARG0, 4ex)
\groupedge[edge below]{pred}{a1}{ARG1}{6ex} % pred -> a1 (ARG1, 6ex)
\end{dependency}

\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=0.2cm]
My \&[.5cm] dog \& also \&[.7cm] likes \&[.4cm] eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, while the pdf renders fine in the html it's only possible to see the textual information of the trees, no edges or other graphical elements.

Comment: I need to generate an html page using htlatex which has some issues with tikz-dependency trees. pdflatex is working fine with me as well.

Comment: The example that you provided did not compile with pdflatex. The corrected version compiles both with pdflatex and htlatex, even though I see no trees (only the text). Could you paste the commands that you are running?

Comment: I am running the same commands that you are running pdflatex *.tex and htlatex *.tex. There are no compilation errors but no trees as well with htlatex which is the problem I want to fix. pdflatex is working fine!

Comment: Oh sorry. I appreciate your help. I am concerned about the html page with tree images which I am unable to produce with htlatex. Forget about the errors my original code has, I somehow missed the end{document} and order as you mentioned that’s not a real issue. I just want the images to be printed in html pages, which is not happening.

Comment: I see. In the output of htlatex I don't see anything suspicious. Maybe the pgf html driver does not support some of the tikz features used by tikz-dependency, such as matrices? I really don't know though, maybe someone with more expertise on htlatex can help (I never used it myself and tikz-dependency was not tested against it).

Comment: BTW, is it necessary to compile it as an html? Can't you just either embed the pdf or convert it to a raster format and include it in an html file?