# What is current status of using tikz with tex4ht?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht

I am completely confused now about how to use tikz with tex4ht, since there seems to be some latest changes and not able to figure what is the way to make it work.

Here is a MWE, which I'd like to compile with make4ht in mathjax mode. But the output does not look correct compared to the PDF

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label =above:$0$,   label =below:{$u=0$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label =above:$\pi$, label =below:{$u_x=0$}] (B) at (4,0);

\draw (A) -- node[above] {$u_t = k u_{xx} $}  node[below] {$f(x)$} ++ (B);

\node at (A)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\node at (B)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now `lualatex` produces this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And `make4ht foo.tex "mathjax"` *or*  `make4ht foo.tex` produces this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The math does not look as good as the PDF. And if I do this `make4ht -ulm foo.tex "mathjax"` it produces this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Changing the MWE to have this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%as before
\end{document}
```

Produces same output which is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ALso adding

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\fi
```

Had no effect.

I looked at [using-htlatex-with-tikz-dependency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158551/using-htlatex-with-tikz-dependency) but answers given are way too complicated and could not follow it. It needs external tools to make them work. inkscape and so on. Which I do not want to use.

What is the **simplest** way to make tikz work with make4ht these days? I am using TL 2018.

Will things change in TL 2019 for tex4ht?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are multiple issues with the `tex4ht` driver at the moment. See https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/651. The `dvisvgm4ht`(used in the answer below) is not without problems either and I gather is slower.

Comment: @DavidPurton Oh no :( well. Will try it once 2019 is installed. If all is lost and it is still not working, I could always generate the PDF's of the pictures using tikz standalone, then use `\includegraphics` to load the output pdf image with tex4ht.

Comment: Don't despair :) The `dvisvgm4ht` driver definitely does a better job. I think it's still a work in progress though.

Comment: @DavidPurton I think the `dvisvgm4ht` works in most cases, I don't recall any open issues. but maybe I just forgot about something. The compilation time can be saved using the `dvisvgm_hashes` extension for `make4ht`. It compiles only changed images and support multiple CPU cores.

Comment: @michal.h21, I found an issue while working on shadings. I'll put in a bug report for you.

Comment: @michal.h21, bug reports submitted at [#1](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht/issues/1) and [#2](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht/issues/2). By the way, I'm most impressed you got even the functional shadings working!

Comment: @DavidPurton thanks, I will take a look. the configuration basically just use the `dvips` definitions and `dvisvgm` for the image production, the `tex4ht` part just marks part of the image that should be converted to an image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compile this file "correctly" with [tex4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht) then it produces the expected HTML file:

[image]

Here "correctly" means that you need to tell pgf the "correct" driver to use by adding the line:

```
 \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
```

to the top of the tex file. If you are using TeXLive 2019 then you will have this file as it is included as part of the [webquiz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/webquiz) package, but this driver file is actually written by Michal Hoftich, who is one of the tex4ht maintainers. You can download the latest version of this driver from https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht.

Here is the modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
   \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label =above:$0$,   label =below:{$u=0$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label =above:$\pi$, label =below:{$u_x=0$}] (B) at (4,0);

\draw (A) -- node[above] {$u_t = k u_{xx} $}  node[below] {$f(x)$} ++ (B);

\node at (A)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\node at (B)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The easiest way to compile this file with [tex4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht) is to use Michal Hoftich's [make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht):

> make4ht filename

Comment: Thanks. I am installing TL 2019 at this moment. It will take 2-3 hrs to finish. Will try with `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}` then. I prefer not to download individual files so installing 2019 would be better option.

Comment: I've send mail to Henri Menke to use the alternative driver as a default one for TikZ and tex4ht.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks. When it hits texlive I'll have to update my package so that it no longer uses it.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks to to your help and ofcourse thanks to Michal.h21 for all his great work on this.

Comment: @Andrew I've fixed some bugs in the `dvisvgm4ht` driver, it can can compile most tikz pictures without compilation errors. The output is sometimes wrong for some more complex images, but it is OK in most cases