# Preserve table formatting in epub?

Tags: tabularx, epub

I have a latex table defined with array and tabularx, see code below.

In the PDF, it looks fine:

[image: tables in PDF]

When I convert it to epub, it gets completely mangled:

[image: tables in epub]

Do I have any hope of fixing that, or should I abandon epub?  I am currently thinking I should probably just distribute the PDF itself, to be sure it looks okay.  However, it would be nice if it could be read on e-readers.

Making epub out of latex is [hard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub).  I ended up using this workflow:

```
latexml --dest tmp/book.xml main.tex
latexmlpost  -dest=tmp/book.html tmp/book.xml
ebook-convert tmp/book.html tmp/book.epub --language en --no-default-epub-cover
```

---

Beginning of latex table code:

```
% centered X for tabularx
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\tx}{{\tt X}}
\newcommand{\ty}{{\tt Y}}

\[
% two rows of five tables each:
\begin{array}{c}

%%%%% FIRST ROW

% five position tables:
\begin{array}{cccc}

% position table 1 (table and caption):
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\tx &   &   & \\ \hline
\ty & \ty & \tx & \\ \hline
  &   &   & \\ \hline
  &   &   & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \\
\textrm{position 1}
\end{array}

% position table 2 (table and caption):
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\tx &   &   & \\ \hline
  &   & \tx & \\ \hline
\ty & \ty & \ty & \ty \\ \hline
  &   &   & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \\
\textrm{position 2}
\end{array}

% position table 3 (table and caption):
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\tx &   &   & \\ \hline
  &   &   & \tx \\ \hline
  &   &   & \\ \hline
  &   &   &   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \\
\textrm{position 3}
\end{array}

% position table 4 (table and caption):
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\tx &   &   & \\ \hline
  &   &   & \tx \\ \hline
\ty & \tx &   & \\ \hline
  &   &   &   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \\
\textrm{position 4}
\end{array}

% position table 4 (table and caption):
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{tabularx}{50pt}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\tx &   &   & \\ \hline
  &   &   & \tx \\ \hline
  & \tx &   & \\ \hline
\ty & \ty & \ty & \ty \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \\
\textrm{position 5}
\end{array}

\end{array}

\\
\\

%%%%% SECOND ROW
% ...
```

Comment: why have you goyt tabularx inside array it's not exactly wrong but rather weird nesting and so not that surprising it confusers convertors. Also as there is no line breaking in teh cells tabularx isn't really doing anything very useful you could replace all the tabularx by `\begin{tabular}{|p{12pt}|p{12pt}|p{12pt}|p{12pt}|}`

Comment: also please always include a complete test file, it is impossible to debug a fragment. and unrelated but `\tt` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993 have you seen it used in a tutorial somewhere? We could try to get the tutorial fixed.