# Research papers in LaTeX to epub

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, tex4ebook, kindle

I really don't have any kind of experience dealing with LaTeX files. I'm just trying to read some research papers released in the field of Deep Learning on my Kindle. Mostly, these papers are released as a pdf file as well as a tar.gz file which contains the .tex file and all the associated images and other contents.

**What I've tried so far:**

First, I tried to directly send the pdf files to my Kindle through mail and the subject "Convert", but it wasn't able to format all the math symbols and the images properly. So, it was overall a disaster.

Then, through a tex.stackexchange [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397344/292761) I came across [tex4ebook](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook) tool for converting LaTeX to epub. Which is really a wonderful tool. From all the convertors I tried so far it was able to convert 3 papers out of 7 without me editing anything. I'm not sure but it feels like the problem is with the tex file created by the authors. So, me having no experience with latex is having difficulty to pinpoint the exact problem.

[This](https://github.com/kiran-pradeep/dl_tex_files) is the link to the github repository I've created to upload the extracted files from all the tar.gz files of the research paper. Out of the 7 research papers I was able to successfully convert ResNet, U-Net and Autoencoders to epub file without any hassle using the code:

```
tex4ebook -f epub3 ${filename}.tex mathml
```

For the others:

1. YOLO - [log](https://github.com/kiran-pradeep/dl_tex_files/blob/main/Error%20logs/YOLO/yolo.log)
2. GANs - [log](https://github.com/kiran-pradeep/dl_tex_files/blob/main/Error%20logs/GANs/adversarial.log)
3. U-Net - [log](https://github.com/kiran-pradeep/dl_tex_files/blob/main/Error%20logs/U-Net/paper459.log)
4. Transformers - [log](https://github.com/kiran-pradeep/dl_tex_files/blob/main/Error%20logs/Transformers/ms.log)
5. Batch Normalization - [log](https://github.com/kiran-pradeep/dl_tex_files/blob/main/Error%20logs/Batch%20Normalization/arx.log)

Can anyone provide a fast and easy solution to solve these problems?

Comment: first one `$\lambda_\textrm{coord}$` should be  `$\lambda_{\textrm{coord}}$` with whole subscript in `{...}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It worked like a charm. It might be a stupid question but how exactly did you debug this fast? Using the log file or going through the .tex file?

Comment: I just glanced at the first error in the first log. (it helps to have spent 30 years debugging tex log files first, makes known issues easier to spot:-)

Comment: see this page for some discussion about issues with commands in superscripts: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#subscripts-and-superscripts